# How to make the layout of the Toplevel windows to be fixed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a few windows, and I want them to stay in the same 'position' compare to the other Toplevel siblings. They still all should be moveable, but just not pop up on the top of others on mouse click. I only know the '-topmost' attribute, but it seems to not work for many windows. So here is just a simple code example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()


class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    move_pos = 0

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry(f'+{self.move_pos}+100')
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.__class__.move_pos += 100
        self.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())


root.withdraw()
for i in range(10):
    Window()

root.mainloop()
```

Note: There are no need to create a logic, if some windows have been 'minimized', because I will use 'overrideredirect' for each of them in my code. Also, the code must work together with overridedirect.

Comment: I think the *'position'* is the *z-order* of the window.  You can try creating window with *previous window as the parent* and a *transient window of the previous window*. That is `window1` is the parent of `window2` and `window2` is a transient window of `window1`.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks. Yes, that will work, but can’t work together with “overridedirect” method unfortunately.

Comment: The z-order works with `.overrideredirect(1)`, just the stacking order is reversed.

Comment: @acw1668 not working for me. Just to note that overridedirect is applying for each of this toplevels, not for the root.

Comment: Yes I know it is applied to all toplevels.

Comment: @acw1668 if possible, can you provide your solution as an answer? Maybe I am doing something wrong, but not sure, what. It doesn't show most of the toplevels.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an ugly one, but AFAIK there is no perfect answer to this question that doesn't link all the windows, or something like this that would make upcoming debugging worse.

What is done is to add an event listener for when the user selects a window, that "updates" all the windows that should be in front of the selected window by setting their `wm_attributes` to `-topmost` again (which forces them back in front in the right order).
The windows are stored in a list that is also used to set their order, and a `topindex` kwarg is added to use when defining a new window. Higher `topindex` values will be placed on top.

Depending on how the OS processes the windows, the order can be wrong when defining the windows. To solve this, we force focus on the back window after generating all the windows, updating them in order.

If you want another window to be selected, I suggest you wait at least a frame after resetting the order.

MRE:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    move_pos = 0

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        assert 'topindex' in kwargs # make sure it's set up properly
        self.topindex = kwargs.pop('topindex') # higher = more on top
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry(f'+{self.move_pos}+300')
        self.__class__.move_pos += 100

        self.attributes('-topmost', 1)
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.move_to_topindex)

    def move_to_topindex(self, evt):
        for i in range(self.topindex, len(windows)):
            windows[i].attributes('-topmost', 1)

windows = [] # last to be added will be on top
root.withdraw()
for i in range(10):
    windows.append(Window(topindex=len(windows)))

# fix order at the start by selecting the back window (updates all)
windows[0].focus()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. Though I thought there could be easier solution (build in methods) to do that.

Comment: Surely. Anyhow this works if a "correct" way doesn't exist.